# KeyError: None while reading from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm quite confused on why I keep getting KeyError: None, I would like to get the user to enter a Name(e.g. Lisbon) and return other Users in the JSON file(e.g. Jade, John) that falls under the same Country as what the User Inputs(e.g. Lisbon), I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{  
   "user1":{  
      "Country":[  
         "China",
         "USA",
         "Nepal"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Lisbon"
      ]
   },
   "user2":{  
      "Country":[  
         "Sweden",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Jade"
      ]
   },
   "user3":{  
      "Country":[  
         "India",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "John"
      ]
   }
}
```

And here's my code

```
userName = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

def getId(name):
  for userId, v in data.items():
    if v['Name'] == name:
        return userId;

id = getId(userName)
for k, v in data.items():
  if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
      print(k)
```

How do I go around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getId` function always returns None. This is because `if v['Name'] == name:` will never succeed. `v['Name']` is a list, and `name` is a string, and a list and a string never compare equal.

If possible, modify the format of your json file so that the Name value is a string, not a list of strings.

```
"user1":{
    "Country":[
        "China", "USA", "Nepal"
    ],
     "Name": "Lisbon"
},
//etc
```

If this is not possible, modify `getId` so it inspects the first element of the list.

```
def getId(name):
  for userId, v in data.items():
    if v['Name'][0] == name:
        return userId
```